# Get commit that precedes a fork at Github

Tags: git, github, fork, commit

There is a way to get the commit that precedes a fork?

Like we have in the Network graph.

Example: https://github.com/fladson/source/network

The commit that precedes the fork is `3578d5c`.

There is a way to get this by API or git?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `git checkout` to go back to a specific commit from your history.  In your case, you'd want:

```
git checkout 3578d5c
```

UPDATE:

You can use the [github api](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/) to find the commit preceding the fork by querying for the forks.  Read through that for the fork you're looking for.  Included with each fork is a "created_at" timestamp.  Save that timestamp.  Then query for the commits passing the "created_at" timestamp in the "since" field.  That will return all of the commits up to when the fork was made.

Here's a ruby script that will return the commit: https://gist.github.com/magikid/bd4a2286b2d08d7eaf99

You'll need to have the octokit gem installed (`gem install octokit`) for the script to work.

Comment: Thanks for replying magikid, but what I want is to first to know which commit preceded the fork, in a programmable solution.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can get the commit that precedes a fork.
When you clone, you clone the entire repository with the entire history. The commit you see as "preceding the fork" is actually not, it's just a starting point from where a new branch has been created, and that branch could have be created months after the fork date: I can fork your repo now on day D where you have 100 commits in your master, then I call pull your branch during 3 months without doing any commit on my own but 3 months later you have 300 commits, then I create a branch from the latest commit which is the 300'th one. So the first commit is 3 month after the fork

Comment: Thanks pomeh, but to confirm that that point was from the new branch, I created another repo to demonstrate that it isnt. Take a look here - https://github.com/fladson/fork_time_test/network - the dot begins when I made the first commit on the fork, with no use of branches. I think I'll contact Github for this. Thanks for replying.